# Can I obtain Kecleon with a Pokéball Plus or gotcha device?

Tags: pokemon-go

With Kecleon (finally) released, I'd like to know if I can obtain it with just using a Pokémon GO Plus device (or similar).

The way to get it, is via spinning a Pokéstop, and a Kecleon would appear on the map. Theoretically, no manual intervention could be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Kecleon must be tapped while it is hiding on the Pokestop in order to appear as a spawn in the wild. A Pokéball Plus or Gotcha will just spin the stop without interacting with the Kecleon, meaning that you will have to wait 5 minutes for the stop to reset in order to (manually) tap the Kecleon.